# Math operations between groups with dplyr and tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

When I have tidy data like this dummy example:

```
    structure(list(year = c(2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2020L), figure = c("income", "income", "income", "income", 
"expenses", "expenses", "expenses", "expenses"), value = c(10, 
11, 10, 13, 5, 4, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .Names = c("year", 
"figure", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

that is:

```
  year   figure value
1 2017   income    10
2 2018   income    11
3 2019   income    10
4 2020   income    13
5 2017 expenses     5
6 2018 expenses     4
7 2019 expenses     4
8 2020 expenses     4
```

and I want to calculate the profit for each year (income - expenses), I use the following approach:

```
temp %>% 
spread(figure, value) %>% 
mutate(profit = income - expenses) %>% 
gather(figure, value, -year)
```

and the output is:

```
   year   figure value
1  2017 expenses     5
2  2018 expenses     4
3  2019 expenses     4
4  2020 expenses     4
5  2017   income    10
6  2018   income    11
7  2019   income    10
8  2020   income    13
9  2017   profit     5
10 2018   profit     7
11 2019   profit     6
12 2020   profit     9
```

I change the table to wide, I do the operation between columns and then I change the data to long format again.

Is there any way with `group_by()` to do the same thing, but without changing to wide format and then to long format?

EDIT:

I I have the following data.frame:

```
temp <- structure(list(year = c(2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2020L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 
2020L), figure = c("income", "income", "income", "income", "expenses", 
"expenses", "expenses", "expenses", "income", "income", "income", 
"income", "expenses", "expenses", "expenses", "expenses"), value = c(10, 
11, 10, 13, 5, 4, 4, 4, 10, 11, 10, 13, 5, 4, 4, 4), company = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B")), .Names = c("year", "figure", "value", "company"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I do:

```
temp %>% 
  filter(company == "A") %>% 
  group_by(year, company) %>% 
  summarise(value = value[figure == 'income'] - value[figure == 'expenses'], 
           figure = 'profit') %>%
  bind_rows(temp, .)
```

The final output contains company "A" and company "B" and the output has to be only "B". The example shows that binding with the original data.frame is not a good idea if we modify the data before to do the summary.

Answer (score 2):

For every `year` you can subtract the `"income"` `value` with `"expenses"` value and bind the result to the original dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(value = value[figure == 'income'] - value[figure == 'expenses'], 
            figure = 'profit') %>%
  bind_rows(df, .)

#   year   figure value
#1  2017   income    10
#2  2018   income    11
#3  2019   income    10
#4  2020   income    13
#5  2017 expenses     5
#6  2018 expenses     4
#7  2019 expenses     4
#8  2020 expenses     4
#9  2017   profit     5
#10 2018   profit     7
#11 2019   profit     6
#12 2020   profit     9
```

---

We can also use `diff` to subtract values after arranging data by `year` and `figure`.

```
df %>%
  arrange(year, figure) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(value = diff(value),
            figure = 'profit') %>%
  bind_rows(df, .)
```

Comment: Nice approach, however if I have some `filter()`, `bind_rows()`, etc. before `summarise()`, then I can't bind the rows with the original data.frame.

Comment: @FrancescVE `filter` should not be a problem since the number of columns don't change in `filter`, with `summarise` the number of columns may/may not change but with `bind_rows` should not be a problem since it adds `NA` if the column is not present. (see `bind_rows(iris, mtcars)`). Can you mention specifically what you are trying to do and if it gives you any error?

Comment: I've edited the original question giving a better example.

Comment: @FrancescVE what would be the expected output for the updated dataframe? If it is same as the one you have with `gather` , then it has column values mixed (`A`, `B` with numbers) also it has got duplicated rows.

Comment: @FrancescVE I am confused about what is the question now. Your original question had input as well as clear expected output to which my answer works correctly. I am not sure what you are looking for in your updated question.